# Генерация enum на лету или альтернатива

Tags: c#

Есть код ранее (был опубликован чуть ранее пользователем @iluxa1810)

```
[Flags]
enum Rights {
    Default = 0x000001,
        Vip = 0x000002 | Default,
        Admins = 0x000004 | Vip,
        FullAdmins = 0x000008 | Admins
}
```

Мне нужно как раз такое же решение, но с загрузкой enum из json.

Есть ли готовый пример или проект?Никак не могу допереть как сделать

Comment: Используйте обычный класс и в рантайме просто создавайте его экземпляры, для удобства можете создать операторы для преобразования в/из int

Answer (score 1):

Enum - это константы, они определяются на стадии компиляции. ([Есть, конечно, извращенные способы, но это вряд ли то, что бы вы хотели сделать.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857414/dynamically-create-an-enum))

В рантайме вы можете использовать`Dictionary<string, int>` для тех же целей.

Comment: мне в принципе подойдет и создание отдельной сборки из того примера.А не подскажите как к тому примеру добавить например после High = 1 | low

Comment: что-то вроде `myEnum.DefineLiteral("High", 1 | lowValue);`. Но создавать сборку под едиственный enum - это то еще извращение, одумайтесь!)

Comment: не работает.Лучше сборку,чем много конфигов

Comment: @fehar, чем просто словарь вас не устроил? Мне сложно представить кейс, когда нужно генерировать enum.

Comment: просто обратился к enum и если больше нужного - выполнить действие.А со словаря парсить больше

Comment: @fehar, чтобы у вас enum появился в рантайме нужно сделать кучу приседаний) а библиотечки, вроде Newnotsoft.Json, все сами спарсят.